# Android - SQLite Update Statement

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am playing with an example of SQLite I found on the internet. I have an update statement like this:

```
public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());

    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?" + 
    contact.getID(), null);

}
```

And an update statement like this:

```
public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());

    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
    new String[]{String.valueOf(contact.getID())});
}
```

Can someone tell me the difference?

Comment: `Can someone tell me the difference?` Can someone (you) please google for a SQLite tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method signature for an update operation on SQLite database.

```
int android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(
        String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

From [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]))

> You may include ?s in the where clause, which will be replaced
>   by the values from whereArgs. The values will be bound as Strings.

Btw your first example wouldn't work cause you have included
"`KEY_ID + " = ?" + contact.getID()`" in  `whereClause` param and kept the `whereArgs` null. The `?s` would'nt be replaced by your arg `contact.getId()`

Change whereClause in 1st example to this: `KEY_ID + " = " + contact.getID()`

Answer (score 0):

On your 1st example.The code can't update anything.

The `update` method `whereCause` params will be convert to some SQL on where case ,It will replace the `?` placeholder with `whereArgs`.

Such as:

In your 1st example.If `contact.getId()` return 1,The final SQL is like:

`update contact set KEY_NAME = 'your contact name ' where KEY_ID = ? 1`

but 2st example final SQL is like:

`update contact set KEY_NAME = 'your contact name ' where KEY_ID = 1`

So,the first example is not work.